# c# MailSender and sleep

Tags: c#, sleep, smtpclient, mail-sender

I am writing a program that sends email through class SmtpClient. I use this code:

```
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("mailSMTP.it");

            mail.From = new MailAddress("address.it");

            mail.Subject = "oggetto";

            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string htmlBody = "someHTML";

            mail.Body = htmlBody;

            SmtpServer.Port = 25;

            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;

            foreach (string indirizzo in indirizzi)
            {
                mail.To.Clear();
                mail.To.Add(indirizzo);
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            }

            MessageBox.Show("e-mail spedite!");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
```

but it only works if I cut the "Sleep" line. Why? I thought it was a good idea to make a rest during that process.

Comment: I don't think so its a good idea to make rest in process.

Comment: works = it sends all emails. Moreover it "works" even if I set a breakpoint at foreach line. Only if i run the code with the sleep function (and without breakpont) I get an exception.

Comment: @StefanoCastelli You should post the details of the exception.

Comment: @Mufaka It is in italian but I think i can translate it as "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"

Answer (score 2):

Given that there's an exception, assuming it's at the call to `Send`, I would suggest not re-using the `MailMessage` object and creating a new one on each iteration of the loop.  for example:

```
        //...
        foreach (string indirizzo in indirizzi)
        {
            string htmlBody = "someHTML";
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage 
            {
                From = new MailAddress("address.it"),
                Subject = "oggetto",
                IsBodyHtml = true,
                Body = htmlBody,
            };

            mail.To.Clear();
            mail.To.Add(indirizzo);
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
```

<s>If by "works" you mean your `MessageBox` shows up in a reasonable amount of time... then the reason is because `Sleep` is blocking the UI thread until all the messages are sent.  e.g. if you try to send 10 messages, the UI will halt for 30 seconds (3000 milliseconds X 10).</s>

Comment: Yes, I know, but the problem is different: I'm testing the program with a List that contains 3 email addresses. With the "Sleep" line it only sends the message to the first address, and then throw and exception. Without the sleep line, it sends all the emails. But i don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

I think you define new thread for this process because if you write                  `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);` means the main thread going to sleep for 3000ms.

So,Create a nested thread for this process and after this you can stop/sleep your thread .

Comment: I think the question is more about a way to do this without using `Sleep`, creating a new thread to avoid blocking the main thread doesn't address the root of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion (and [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096794/is-sleep-evil)) you should try to avoid Sleep at almost any cost, more often than not you end up with an application that behaves strange (like the behavior you describe).

I would solve it with a timer that uses an index to determine which is the next mail to send. Something like this:

```
    try
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("mailSMTP.it");

        mail.From = new MailAddress("address.it");

        mail.Subject = "oggetto";

        mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        string htmlBody = "someHTML";

        mail.Body = htmlBody;

        SmtpServer.Port = 25;

        SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;

        var index = 0;

        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((callbackState) =>
            {
                mail.To.Clear();
                mail.To.Add(indirizzi[index]);
                SmtpServer.Send(mail);

                index++;

                if (index < indirizzi.Count)
                  timer.Change(3000, Timeout.Infinite);
                else {
                    timer.Dispose();
                    Invoke(new Action(DisplayAllEmailsSentMessage));
                }
            }, timer, 3000, Timeout.Infinite);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
```

Note that you would have to use Invoke to interact with Windows Forms in any way, for instance to show a message box. This is because the Threading.Timer callback executes on a thread of its own.

It may also be possible for you to use the Windows.Forms.Timer, but I rarely use it myself since it's in the Windows.Forms namespace and thus only suitable for UI's written in Windows Forms.

Answer (score 0):

The Smtp server is dropping your connection due to inactivity. This is most likely to free up resources on the server.

From the [SmtpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) documentation:

> The connection established by the current instance of the SmtpClient
>   class to the SMTP server may be re-used if an application wishes to
>   send multiple messages to the same SMTP server. This is particularly
>   useful when authentication or encryption are used establish a
>   connection to the SMTP server. The process of authenticating and
>   establishing a TLS session can be expensive operations. A requirement
>   to re-establish a connection for each message when sending a large
>   quantity of email to the same SMTP server could have a significant
>   impact on performance.

In general, the other responders are correct in saying that you shouldn't be sleeping between sending. The Smtp server *should* be robust enough to handle all the emails you can throw at it sequentially.

Comment: After a lot of tests, I think this is the real problem: If I set a shorter sleep time (e.g. 100 ms) it sends all the emails, so I guess the problem is caused by SMTP server inactivity. I'm still testing with other solutions proposed (many thanks to all!!!), I'll let you know...

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

 class MailSender
    {
        public static int CreateMessageMdp(String destination,String mdp)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new SmtpClient("smtp.domain.com", 587)
                {
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential("appgestionali@domain.com", "password"),
                    EnableSsl = true
                };
                DateTime localDate = DateTime.Now;
                string body = "Suite à votre demande de mot de passe le " + localDate.ToString("F") + "\n on vous envoi votre mot de passe est :" + mdp;
                client.Send("appgestionali@domain.com", destination, "Information", body);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(""+ ex.GetBaseException());
                return -1;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```